# Split MongoDB data into several files

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've been reading about split Mongo databases and escalate through [shards](http://blog.zawodny.com/2011/03/06/mongodb-pre-splitting-for-faster-data-loading-and-importing/), but I'm thinking if possible to split a mongo database in the same server by chunks and store that in different files, the range of shard keys will be calculated using a formula considering the number of week and the current year something like (year)x54 + current week number of the year

let's say 2010x54 + 11 = 108551

Ideally what I have in mind is to split the files by month like the following:

```
chunk01 (shardKeyID 108551 -> 108555) ----> Server1---> physical file 01
chunk02 (shardKeyID 108556 -> 108560) ----> Server1---> physical file 02
chunk03 (shardKeyID 108561 -> 108565) ----> Server1---> physical file 03
```

I've tried to do it in a single server, but if I it set up for shards I just get a subset of the documents in the DB, something that make sense because the other part will be stores in the other shard in a different server.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a shard cluster on a single server by running separate `mongod` instances on different ports. Instructions can be found in [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/).

Regarding the splitting of chunks, this is handled automatically by the database. Be aware that by default, your collection will shard using the default chunk size of 64MB. See more details [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-clusters/):

> Chunk size is user configurable. However, the default value is of 64
>   megabytes is ideal for most deployments.

You seem to be describing your own algorithm for when to balance, this is not possible. You will really need to leave it to [cluster balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/#sharding-balancing-internals) to figure this out for you.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB automatically creates data files (referred to as *extents*) for each database; you cannot control which documents go into a given physical data file as you are suggesting.

[Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) distributes a single logical database across a cluster of servers, where each shard is backed by either a replica set (recommended) or a single mongod.  Your [choice of shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/#choosing-a-shard-key) determines the properties that will be used to balance the data across shards, but again you are not determining where data lives within a physical data file.